# MyBatis: Attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, mybatis

My DB connection is with mybatis, 
I have DAO with this function:

```
public int getUpdateTaskStateStart(Task task);
```

And the implemention is located in XML file:

```
<select id="getUpdateTaskStateStart" resultType="Integer" parameterType="com.ladpc.mobile.entities.Task">

        SELECT START_UPDATE
        FROM UPDATE_TASK_STATE
            WHERE 
        TASK_ID = #{taskId} AND RASHUT_ID=#{rashutId} 

    </select>
```

In DB, I have table UPDATE_TASK_STATE, that include START_UPDATE filed.

My problem is that when I run `getUpdateTaskStateStart(Task)` (and send task param that include rashutId="248" and taskId="2449" fileds inside), I get Error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Mapper method 'com.ladpc.mobile.dao.AssesmentTasksDao.getUpdateTaskStateStart attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (int).
```

What is wrong with my function? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mapper XML specifies `resultType="Integer"`, but `getUpdateTaskStateTask()` wants to return a primitive int, not the Integer wrapper class.

Change it to `resultType="int"`.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace states, that your method is returning "NULL", but the method has an "int" return type, which is a primitve data type in Java, therefore cannot return "NULL" value.

Change the method's return type to its wrapper class, "Integer", then at least the exception will be gone.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Select> -> Null, <Update> -> int
```

org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Update;