# How can I modify the default IntegerTypeHandler in Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I try to use <select> to query int value in mysql with mybatis, it return null when nothing matches.

Howerver the corresponding method in XXXMapper.java return the primitive type int, which case exception:  attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (int).

So i want to modify the default IntegerTypeHandler in mybatis, i want MyConfigIntegerTypeHandler returns -1 when nothing found.

I know the best way to solve this problem is to modify the method defination, to make the query method return Integer rather than int. I just want to know how to fix it without corrent the origin code.

Comment: You can register the type handler globally in the config (see the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers)).

Comment: You need to implement a [`ResultHandler`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/session/ResultHandler.html) not a `TypeHandler` in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MyBatis: Attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068543/mybatis-attempted-to-return-null-from-a-method-with-a-primitive-return-type)